# Remove spaces in HTML via jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, magento

I'm trying to set some anchor links based on dynamic but running into issues due to ID's with spaces in them. For example I have this:

```
<a href="#shoes">Shoes</a>
<a href="#Socks and Sandals"></a>

<div class="foot" id="shoes"></div>
<div class="foot" id="Socks and Sandals"></div>
```

When I need this:

```
<a href="#shoes">Shoes</a>
<a href="#SocksandSandals"></a>

<div class="foot" id="shoes"></div>
<div class="foot" id="SocksandSandals"></div>
```

EDIT: If I had the following:

```
<a href="#shoes">Shoes</a>
    <a href="#SocksandSandals"></a>

    <div class="foot" title="shoes"></div>
    <div class="foot" tile="Socks and Sandals"></div>
```

How would I use jQuery to generate the this:

```
<a href="#shoes">Shoes</a>
        <a href="#SocksandSandals"></a>

        <div class="foot" title="shoes" id="shoes"></div>
        <div class="foot" tile="Socks and Sandals" id="SocksandSandals"></div>
```

Comment: You can't have space in element id.

Comment: The place to correct is your HTML/<code that produces your HTML> and replace those ids with valid ones.

Comment: How are you generating the markup?

Comment: The markup is being generated via PHP. If I put the data in as different attribute (title for example), would it be possible to remove the spaces and add the IDs via Jquery?

Comment: you cannot have some spaces in the HTML, but you can still use the multiple IDs CSS selector: `#Socks#and#Sandals`

Comment: Why don't you remove the spaces in the PHP? `$string = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $string);` This would be the correct way to do it. You could do something similar with jQuery if you put it in a `data-*` attribute, but doing it in PHP will cause less problems.

Comment: <li id="<?php echo $catLevel2->getName(); ?>"> (magento template file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could alternatively clean them up after the PHP output using jQuery... just make sure you use this prior to doing anything else JavaScript-wise with your elements (as you won't be able to call them properly by ID):

```
$('div').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('id',$(this).attr('id').replace(/\s/g, ''));
});
$('a').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href').replace(/\s/g, ''));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5pX4P/2/

Edit: To allow the 'title' attribute to be the original ID (with spaces):

```
$('div').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('title',$(this).attr('id'));
    $(this).attr('id',$(this).attr('id').replace(/\s/g, ''));
});
$('a').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href').replace(/\s/g, ''));
});
```

Here you can see I made this modification, and also gave each DIV a heading based on their original title; I also created a 'return to top' link for each to bring you back to the beginning of the document... isn't coding fun?!

http://jsfiddle.net/5pX4P/3/

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the code might have something like this:

```
$items = array("Shoes", "Socks and Sandals");
foreach ($items as $item)
    echo "<a href=\"#{$item}\">$item</a>";
foreach ($items as $item)
    echo "<div class=\"foot\" id=\"{$item}\"></div>";
```

That generates something similar to this:

```
<a href="#shoes">Shoes</a>
<a href="#Socks and Sandals"></a>

<div class="foot" id="shoes"></div>
<div class="foot" id="Socks and Sandals"></div>
```

You can make a small change in your PHP code:

```
strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", $item))
```

Or like you expected, you can do something like below, which removes all the spaces:

```
strtolower(str_replace(" ", "", $item))
```

The above one replaces all the spaces with `-`s. Using jQuery, you won't be able to do for those elements that have spaces in their IDs.

---

To answer your updated question, you can use the following code to match the `div`s and links with the `title` attribute:

```
$('div[title]').each(function(){
    $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr('id').replace(/\s/g, ''));
});
$('a[title]').each(function(){
    $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr('href').replace(/\s/g, ''));
});
```